# How to send random themed Pictures?

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

Im coding right now a Discord Bot that shoukd send random Picutes or Gifs
For example Random Wallpapers,Random Gifs,Anime Gifs
or something like that...
Anyone knows how?
My Coding language is JavaScript.

Answer (score 0):

You could use something like [unsplash](https://unsplash.com/developers) or something similar to search for the specific search term.

To send the images as an [attachment](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/TextChannel?scrollTo=send) in discord.js, you can get the image or send the URL of the image:

```js
channel.send({
  files: [search_image_url_or_buffer]
})
```